# How to evaluate the integral

Tags: integration

Can some one provide me hint to evaluate  the following integral.

$$
\int\csc^{2}\left(x\right)
\ln\left(\cos\left(x\right) - \sqrt{\vphantom{\largeA}\,\cos\left(2x\right)\,}\,\right)
\,{\rm d}x
$$.

Comment: what is $cosec$?

Comment: @Rustyn: I guess $\text{cosec}\:x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$ (Cosecant)

Comment: Common notation is $\csc$, I guess I could be wrong though. My bad.

Comment: @Rustyn: In some old books $\text{cosec}$ is used too.

Comment: @user35603 Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In fact with some trigonometry, we can simplify the integrand, in the formula of David H. (after the integration by parts step):
$$
\cot x \cdot\frac{-\sin x+\frac{\sin 2x }{\sqrt{\cos 2x }}}{\cos{ x}-\sqrt{\cos 2x }}=
\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x\cdot\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 x}}+\cot^2x
$$
This yields the following
$$
\int \csc^2(x)\log(\cos{ x}-\sqrt{\cos 2x }) dx=-\cot x\cdot\log(\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos 2x })-\cot x-x-\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\sin x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: integration by parts is a great candidate for a first step here. Using $\int\csc^2{x}\,dx=-\cot{x}$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\log{\left(\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos{2x}}\right)}=\frac{-\sin{x}+\frac{\sin{2x}}{\sqrt{\cos{2x}}}}{\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos{2x}}},$$

we arrive at:

$$\int\csc^2{x}\log{\left(\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos{2x}}\right)}dx\\
=-\cot{x}\log{\left(\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos{2x}}\right)}-\int\cot{x}\cdot\frac{\sin{x}-\frac{\sin{2x}}{\sqrt{\cos{2x}}}}{\cos{x}-\sqrt{\cos{2x}}}dx.$$

Comment: I corrected a typo in the formula for the derivative of the logarithmic term. Presumably that was the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

MAPLE returns
$$-\cot(x)\ln(\cos(x)-\sqrt{\cos(2x)})-\cot \left( x \right)  +x-\sqrt { \left( -2\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+1 \right)  \left(  \left( 
\cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-1 \right) } \left( -1/2\,{\frac {-
2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+2\, \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{2}+\cos \left( x \right) -1}{\sqrt { \left( -\cos
 \left( x \right) -1 \right)  \left( 2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{3}-2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-\cos
 \left( x \right) +1 \right) }}}+1/2\,{\frac {-2\, \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{3}-2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
+\cos \left( x \right) +1}{\sqrt { \left( 1-\cos \left( x \right) 
 \right)  \left( 2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+2\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-\cos \left( x \right) -1
 \right) }}} \right)  \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{-1}{
\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-1}}}$$

It seems you have a tricky integral on your hands. If I find a substitution that returns this I'll post

Comment: *Mathematica* returns the far simpler result $$-\csc x\bigg\{\sqrt{\cos2x}+x\sin x+\cos x\Big[1+\ln\!\Big(\!\!\cos x-\sqrt{\cos2x}\Big)\Big]\bigg\}.$$